# Какие нейросети выбрать под данные типы задач?

Tags: нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

Пытаюсь как-то уложить все в голове, интересует какие сети лучше подойдут для задач и почему

Знаю, некоторые задачи решаются вовсе не сетями, но легче сказать конечную цель, чем абстрактно описывать сеть, которую я бы хотел найти

Допустим, задачи такие:

1. Распознавание голоса
2. Обучение музыкальному вкусу и поиск похожих песен
3. Контроль температуры инерционной системы (нужно очень быстрое обучение прям в процессе, иначе что-то может перегреется или переохладится)
4. Распознавание графиков (допустим, спектра)
5. Научить узнавать человека с камеры по одному его фото

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует несколько основных типов нейронный сетей которые используются для решения некоторых типов задач. **Очень и очень кратко**:

**FFNN** Сеть прямого распространения - самая простая и в основном используется для анализа данных в которых можно выявить повторяющийся паттерн.

**RNN** Рекурентная нейронная сеть - сеть которая делает вывод основываясь не только на настоящих данных но и на прошедших. Используется там где важно учитивать влияние нескольких факторов.

**LSTM** Сеть с длинной и короткой памятью - подвид рекурентных сетей, но в отличии от обычной рекурентной сети может запоминать данные на долгий период иными словами понимать контекст.

**CNN** Сверточная нейронная сеть - НС которая обрабатывает данные с помощью фильтров и сети прямого распространения.

Отвечая на Ваш вопрос:

1 и 2 - **LSTM**. Все что связанно с обработкой речи и анализом текста нуждается в контексте, также по умолчанию предложение это последовательная расстановка слов которые связанны друг с другом по смыслу.

3 - **FFNN**. Не совсем понял суть но если логика заключается в том чтобы в заисимости от набора факторов выставлять температуру то сеть прямого распространения подойдет лучше всего.

4 - Либо **FFNN** либо **RNN** в зависимости от сложности и "предсказуемости" графика.

5 - **CNN**. Все что связанно с распознавание обьектов и анализом фото или видео, всегда используется сверточная нейронная сеть.

Comment: Спасибо, я уж думал мне никто не ответит.

Comment: На счет 3 пункта, я имел ввиду аналог ПИД на нейросети

Comment: На счет 4 пункта, можете ответить, что подразумевается под сложностью? И предсказуемостью. Допустим, есть спектры которые отличаются друг от друга совсем немного (на 0.5%), подвержены шумам и немного искажаются со временем. Что лучше выбрать?

Comment: На счет ПИД подсказать не смогу так как не знаю все аспекты работы устройства. На счет 4 пункта, в таком случае лучше брать FFNN.

Comment: Ещё вопрос, хочу сделать генерацию светомузыки на LSTM сети, на вход хочу кормить записи с концертов (картинка + звук), а на выходе получать, допустим, просто квадрат который меняет цвет в зависимости от самой мелодии, как надо организовать архитектуру подобного приложения?